# Rhino Mocks - Raise Event When Property Set

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I want to raise an event on a stub object whenever a certain property is set using Rhino Mocks. E.g.

```
public interface IFoo
{
   int CurrentValue { get; set; }
   event EventHandler CurrentValueChanged;
}
```

Setting `CurrentValue` will raise the `CurrentValueChanged` event

I have tried `myStub.Expect(x => x.CurrentValue).WhenCalled(y => myStub.Raise...` which doesn't work because the property is settable and it says I'm setting expectations on a property which is already defined to use PropertyBehaviour. Also I am aware that this is an abuse of `WhenCalled` which I'm none too happy about.

What the correct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most probably created a stub, not a mock. The only difference is that the stub has property behavior by default.

So the full implementation is something like the following:

```
IFoo mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFoo>();
// variable for self-made property behavior
int currentValue;

// setting the value: 
mock
  .Stub(x => CurrentValue = Arg<int>.Is.Anything)
  .WhenCalled(call =>
    { 
      currentValue = (int)call.Arguments[0];
      myStub.Raise(/* ...*/);
    })

// getting value from the mock
mock
  .Stub(x => CurrentValue)
  // Return doesn't work, because you need to specify the value at runtime
  // it is still used to make Rhinos validation happy
  .Return(0)
  .WhenCalled(call => call.ReturnValue = currentValue);
```

Comment: I can't believe how much work needs to go in to get some pretty simple behaviour. But amazingly your code does indeed work. Thanks!

Comment: @RichK: Yes, it is complicated. I've never had to do such a setup. I wonder if you actually need this or if you misuse the mock framework to rebuild logic of another component.